# C++ passing a callback with a range parameter

Tags: c++, templates, callback, std-ranges

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
void mycallback(auto v)
{
    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}

void f(auto cb) {
    cb(std::vector<int>{44,55,66});
    cb(std::vector<int>{123, 234, 345} | std::ranges::views::drop(1));
}

void run()
{
    f(mycallback);
    f([](auto v) {
        for (auto x : v) {
            std::cout << x << '\n';
        }
    });
}
```

`mycallback()` should accept a C++20 range of integers. To be more specific I'll need `owning_view` with miscellaneous filters. So it is a template. I need to pass this callback to `f()` which can call the callback with different range types. I need it to accept mainly lambdas. The `f()` can't be instantiated because compiler doesn't know how to deduce the type since the callback instantiation is required inside the `f()` function.

```
test.cpp:34:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:41:6: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘auto:25’
   41 |     f(mycallback);
```

Is there some lazy instantiation option?

Comment: Make `mycallback` a functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a lambda that calls the callback.

And for the callback to work with ranges, change the signature to `auto&& v`, so that it can accept r-value references as arguments.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1KbYrGM6K)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

void mycallback(auto&& v) {
    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void f(auto cb) {
    cb(std::vector<int>{44, 55, 66});
    cb(std::vector<int>{123, 234, 345} | std::ranges::views::drop(1));
}

int main() {
    f([](auto&& v) { return mycallback(v); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mycallback` is very similar to function template due to the `auto` parameter.
And in this line:

```
f(mycallback);
```

The compiler doesn't know with which type (for the `auto` parameter) to instantiate it.

Instead you can make it a **functor** - i.e. a class with `operator()`.
You can also make the call operator accept `v` bv `auto &&` for types that will otherwise be copied.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

class mycallback
{
public:
    void operator()(auto && v) const
    {
        for (auto const & x : v) {
            std::cout << x << '\n';
        }
    }
};

void f(auto cb) {
    cb(std::vector<int>{44, 55, 66});
    cb(std::vector<int>{123, 234, 345} | std::ranges::views::drop(1));
}

int main()
{
    f(mycallback{});
}
```

Output:

```
44
55
66
234
345
```